Design of a method and data structures to process various data types
I need a method in C that is able to process a data packet that can be of various formats/types. What would be your recommended approach to do so (note that I want to be MISRA compliant as much as possible). Currently, I am considering the following options (but open to learn additional ones), as per the code oultined below
Option 1: the method explicitly states the format of the data packet (and there is a switch case inside the method)
Option 2: the data includes the data type and a union with the content
Which of these options would you prefer?
Many thanks for your insights

int process_type1(const struct type1* data) {

    /* do stuff with data */
}

int process_type2(const struct type2* data) {

    /* do stuff with data */
}


/* Option 1: explicit data type in method to process data */

int process_1(const enum data_type data_type, const uint8_t* data, const size_t* n_bytes) {

    int res = -1;

    switch (data_type) {
        case TYPE_1: res = process_type1((const struct type1*)data); break;
        case TYPE_2: res = process_type2((const struct type2*)data); break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return res;
}


/* Option 2: implicit data type in method to process data and union to include the data */
struct packet {
    enum data_type {
        TYPE_1,
        TYPE_2,
        /* Add more types as needed */
    } data_type;

    union {
        struct type1 type1;
        struct type2 type2;
        /* Add more types as needed */
    } data;
};

int process_2(const struct packet* packet) {
    int res = -1;

    switch (packet->data_type) {
        case TYPE_1:
            res = process_type1(&packet->data.type1);
            break;
        case TYPE_2:
            res = process_type2(&packet->data.type2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return res;
}


Option #2 looks better in the way that it offers a stateful data structure.

Let's focus on C first. Accessing *(const struct type1*)data may be invalid, as maybe breaking alignment and endianess. Is the input data guaranteed to be correct for the types? Is the input buffer guaranteed to contain correct data? As for MIRSA, MISRA 2012 advisory rule 19.2 just states "unions should not be used", for the exact the reasons that are problems with your code - padding, alignment, endianess (and bit-otder) may be all invalid in your code, making both options not valid. If you want to be MISRA compatible, consider unpacking the data yourself, byte by byte.

Overall, structs and unions are problematic for portable modelling of raw byte streams, such as data protocols:

There might be alignment concerns as well as padding. MISRA C's (11.3) main argument against wild and crazy pointer conversions is alignment.
There might be a different network endianness.
Type punning between raw byte streams and struct/union could cause "strict aliasing" undefined behavior.
MISRA C prohibits the use of the same memory area for two unrelated purposes. You may only use union type punning between different representations of the same data, which wouldn't be the case here.

As for (const struct type1*)data followed by a de-refencing of type1 members, it is a strict aliasing violation and undefined behavior, regardless of MISRA. It doesn't matter if uint8_t is a character type because the character type exception to the strict aliasing rules is only valid when going from a larger type to a character type, not the other way around. (Unless you use another trick which I will show further down.)
The only truly portable, well-defined, MISRA-compliant way is to write serialization/deserialization routines that copy the data member by member. Which you will have to do anyway in case facing a different network endianness compared to your CPU endianness. The down side to this is that you have to copy the data.

Otherwise, this is a possible work-around:

Ditch the struct type1 style so that we may change type1 to a union type without changing our whole code. Are there technical reasons to pick one struct coding style over the other?

Make type1 a union like this:


typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    // specific members
  };
  uint8_t raw_data [expected_size];
} type1;

This assuming uint8_t is a character type (pretty much dead certain in practice). After determining the type of the packet, have the function take a uint8_t* parameter. We may now cast that parameter into a type1* because we now have "a union type with a member compatible with the effective type of the object" (uint8_t). That's another exception to the strict aliasing rule.
Furthermore we no longer type pun between two unrelated structs, but rather between the incoming raw data and one of the possible struct types.
The anonymous struct style above is optional, but it allows us to type type.member rather than type.some_struct.member. MISRA C does not object against anonymous struct/union.
We may now cook up a generic API like:
typedef enum {
  TYPE_1,
  TYPE_2,
  /* ... */
  TYPE_N
} data_t;

typedef result_t process_func_t (const uint8_t* raw_data);

result_t process_type1 (const uint8_t* raw_data); // type-specific protocol parser
...

process_func_t* const process[] =  // branch table
{
  [TYPE1] = process_type1,
  [TYPE2] = process_type2,
  ...
};

// ensure integrity between enum and branch table:
_Static_assert(sizeof(process)/sizeof(*process) == TYPE_N,
               "process look-up table inconsistent");

Usage:
data_t data_type;
...
if(data_type < TYPE_1 || data_type >= TYPE_N)
{
  /* defensive programming, error handling here */
}

// assuming raw_data is aligned as per the requirements of the various struct types, then:
process[data_type](raw_data);

This is pretty standard code for safety-related software. And as far as I can tell, MISRA compliant, apart from the cast from uint8_t* to type1* etc that we put inside process_type1. A MISRA deviation from rule 11.3 might be necessary. We don't want a permanent deviation against that rule, because it's a very sound one.

Thanks @Lundin for your detailed answer. I guess that, as you state "no longer type pun between two unrelated structs, but rather between the incoming raw data and one of the possible struct types", there would be a cast within process_type1 to map the raw bytes to the proper struct, right?
result_t process_type1 (const uint8_t* raw_data) { union type1* type1 = (union type1*)raw_data; /* do stuff */ return res;}


@mgfernan Yes and that is made possible by switching to a union. You still have to ensure that the incoming raw_data is aligned appropriately though.

Downsides of both options

Option #1 requires you to pass several variables to the process. As they are separate, you need to keep track of which type is used, which might slow down the development process.

Option #2 will face some problems if type 1, type 2 or any type added further down the road has a different size. In that case the safest way to deal with that would be to make sure other smaller types have "stuff bits" (preferably all zeroes) that align all types to the same size.


Benefits of both options

Option #1 is more explicit in its working, and when something does break, it will be easier to debug. I don't know much about MISRA, but this option seems more in line with its guidelines.

Option #2 is much more concise, so it simply "looks pretty".


